# How do I move a player with a part in roblox?

Tags: lua, roblox

I'm working on a game.
I didn't know if it's broken in the actual game so I fired it up in a test world.

https://streamable.com/ifaatg is me playing around with it

How do I get the player to move on the cyan block? Did roblox just make this feature cringe?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by manipulating the [Humanoid](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/class/Humanoid) using [CFrames](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/articles/Understanding-CFrame).

Get the Humanoids [Rootpart](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/property/Humanoid/RootPart)

> HumanoidRootPart, which is the root driving part of the Humanoid, that
> controls a humanoid’s movement through the game world.
>
> The RootPart is the RootPart of the Humanoid Model's assembly. As
> such, **if a developer wishes to move the Humanoid they should do so via
> the RootPart**

Just find out how people implement trains, cars and such.

You basically get the position of the block and update the Humanoids position each frame.